# Why is squaring a number faster than multiplying two random numbers?

Tags: algorithm, math, bit-manipulation, discrete-mathematics

Multiplying two binary numbers takes n^2 time, yet squaring a number can be done more efficiently somehow.  (with n being the number of bits)  How could that be?

Or is it not possible?  This is insanity!

Comment: Where did you see this insanity?

Comment: My algorithms class at Berkeley :)

Comment: It can't be right, you must be doing some absurd there.

Comment: Does your algorithms prof (or the class materials) have an explanation of how to do this?

Comment: Nope, just left us hanging.  We either have to show how squaring a number can be done more efficiently than multiplying two numbers, or disprove the possibility.

Comment: Why is this a vote down?  Sheesh.

Comment: Good question... I just tagged it Homework since the OP admitted as such in comments - but I haven't voted either way.

Comment: Hey Jess, I'm pretty sure there is an O(n log n) algorithm for squaring a number. I just spent 30mins trying to figure it out, I'm flushing out the details I'll post the outline tmmrw, I have to sleep now.

Comment: Insanity? THIS... IS... STACKOVERFLOW!

Comment: @gmatt: multiplication too can be done in almost O(n log n) - O(n*log(n)*log(log(n))). see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fürer%27s_algorithm

Comment: Binary multiplication is emphatically not O(n^2); knowing most of the EECS profs at Berkeley, I find it very unlikely that any of them would make this claim.  Only the naive schoolbook algorithm requires O(n^2).

It's true that squaring can be implemented somewhat more efficiently than multiplication, because of certain symmetries, but it's only a constant factor speedup (iirc); useful for saving circuits in hardware, but it has very little effect on software.

Comment: Once you factor in the constants, the naive algorithm for multiplication is almost always the fastest in real-world usages.

Comment: If squaring is much faster, we could convert any multiplication into difference of two squares, eg. `45 * 55 = (50 - 5) * (50 + 5) = 50^2 - 5^2` and `45 * 56 = 45 + 45 * 55 = 45 + 50^2 - 5^2`

Answer (score 71, accepted):

1. There exist algorithms more efficient than O(N^2) to multiply two numbers (see Karatsuba, Pollard, Schönhage–Strassen, etc.)
2. The two problems "multiply two arbitrary N-bit numbers" and "Square an arbitrary N-bit number" have the same complexity.

We have

```
4*x*y = (x+y)^2 - (x-y)^2
```

So if squaring N-bit integers takes O(f(N)) time, then the product of two arbitrary N-bit integers can be obtained in O(f(N)) too.  (that is 2x N-bit sums, 2x N-bit squares, 1x 2N-bit sum, and 1x 2N-bit shift)

And obviously we have

```
x^2 = x * x
```

So if multiplying two N-bit integers takes O(f(N)), then squaring a N-bit integer can be done in O(f(N)).

Any algorithm computing the product (resp the square) provides an algorithm to compute the square (resp the product) with the same asymptotic cost.

As noted in other answers, the algorithms used for fast multiplication can be simplified in the case of squaring.  The gain will be on the constant in front of the f(N), and not on f(N) itself.

Comment: omg, thank you! I can't believe I missed that. This answer should be selected as answering the question.

Comment: It's almost always wrong to confuse 'faster' and 'having a lower bound to asymptotic complexity'

Comment: It's worthwhile to note that replacing the product of two 8-bit numbers with the difference-of-squares form converts the problem from one with 16 bits of input to two separate problems which each have 8 bits of input.  On some 8-bit processors which didn't have any hardware-multiply facilities, that could be a major win (think lookup tables).

Comment: Given that the sum or difference of two n-bit numbers takes n+1 bit, what saved using tables of 2n-bit values was knowing squares are odd when the number is odd, and the next bit is always 0 (or hand-wave about numbers being signed).

Comment: For me that is not the answer for the question but the reason for the question. It does solve the problem. It simply says you can either derive multiplication from squaring or squaring from multiplication but not explain which way to go.

Answer (score 15):

Squaring an n digit number may be faster than multiplying two random n digit numbers. Googling I found [this article](http://dspace.lib.fcu.edu.tw/bitstream/2377/11127/1/ce07ics002008000074.pdf). It is about arbitrary precision arithmetic but it may be relevant to what your asking. In it the authors say this:

> In squaring a large integer, i.e. X^2
>   = (xn-1, xn-2, ... , x1, x0)^2 many cross-product terms of the form xi *
>   xj and xj * xi are equivalent. They
>   need to be computed only once and then
>   left shifted in order to be doubled.
>   An n-digit squaring operation is
>   performed using only (n^2 + n)/2
>   single-precision multiplications.

Comment: I was hoping someone would come up with a squaring algorithm that's provably better than generalized multiplication!  It's still O(N^2) though, and I get the impression that Jess is looking for something more like an order of magnitude improvement.

Comment: it is a _binary_ order of magnitute improvement

Answer (score 7):

Like others have pointed out, squaring can only be about 1.5X or 2X faster than regular multiplication between arbitrary numbers. Where does the computational advantage come from? It's symmetry. Let's calculate the square of `1011` and try to spot a pattern that we can exploit. `u0:u3` represent the bits in the number from the most significant to the least significant.

```
    1011 //                               u3 * u0 : u3 * u1 : u3 * u2 : u3 * u3
   1011  //                     u2 * u0 : u2 * u1 : u2 * u2 : u2 * u3       
  0000   //           u1 * u0 : u1 * u1 : u1 * u2 : u1 * u3                 
 1011    // u0 * u0 : u0 * u1 : u0 * u2 : u0 * u3
```

If you consider the elements `ui * ui` for `i=0, 1, ..., 4` to form the diagonal and ignore them, you'll see that the elements `ui * uj` for `i ≠ j` are repeated twice.

Therefore, all you need to do is calculate the product sum for elements below the diagonal and double it, with a left shift. You'd finally add the diagonal elements. Now you can see where the 2X speed up comes from. In practice, the speed-up is about 1.5X because of the diagonal and extra operations.

Answer (score 6):

I believe you may be referring to [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) .  This technique isn't used for multiplying, but for raising to a power x^n, where n may be large.  Rather than multiply x
times itself N times, one performs a series of squaring and adding operations which can be mapped to the binary representation of N. The number of multiplication operations (which are more expensive than additions for large numbers) is reduced from N to log(N) with respect to the naive exponentiation algorithm.

Comment: Almost, but squaring, by definition, means that n = 2

Comment: @Bryan: I am taking some liberties in interpreting Jess's question.  As stated, it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I don't think this is what she is going for. Let me rephrase that. I don't think this is what her prof is going for ;)

Comment: @gmatt: My answer is pretty much a quote from the notes I took in one of my UC Berkeley CS classes.  Jess: If you want to impress your prof,   read up on Karatsuba multiplication and ask why he's wasting your time with O(N^2) multiplication when there's an O(N^1.585) alternative!

Comment: If you're going to brown-nose, do it properly and at least learn about Toom-Cook, if not one of the FFT-based methods =)

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you want to expand out the multiplication `(a+b)×(c+d)`.  It splits up into four individual multiplications: `a×c + a×d + b×c + b×d`.

But if you want to expand out `(a+b)²`, then it only needs three multiplications (and a doubling): `a² + 2ab + b²`.

(Note also that two of the multiplications are themselves squares.)

Hopefully this just begins to give an insight into some of the speedups that are possible when performing a square over a regular multiplication.

Comment: And `a` and `b` can be strategically chosen such that `a` is the high part of the number and `b` is the low part of the number, each with half the significant bits. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/922515/2760

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean multiplying a number by a power of 2? This is usually quicker than multiplying any two random numbers since the result can be calculated by simple bit shifting. However, bear in mind that modern microprocessors dedicate lots of brute force silicon to these types of calculations and most arithmetic is performed with blinding speed compared to older microprocessors

Comment: We can easily create a case for squaring a power of 2.  The question is, can this be done for all squares?  If not, is there a way we can disprove its possibility?

Comment: By definition, squaring is to the power of two. ^3 is called cubing (or 'to the power of three'). ^n is called 'to the power of n'

Answer (score 3):

I have it!

```
2 * 2
```

is more expensive than

```
2 << 1
```

(The caveat being it only works for one case.)

Comment: Squaring is not equivalent to multiplying by two.

Answer (score 1):

First of all great question! I wish there were more questions like this.

So it turns out that the method I came up with is O(n log n) for general multiplication in the arithmetic complexity only. You can represent any number X as

```
X = x_{n-1} 2^{n-1} + ... + x_1 2^1 + x_0 2^0
Y = y_{m-1} 2^{m-1} + ... + y_1 2^1 + y_0 2^0
```

where

```
x_i, y_i \in {0,1}
```

then

```
XY = sum _ {k=0} ^ m+n r_k 2^k
```

where

```
r_k = sum _ {i=0} ^ k x_i y_{k-i}
```

which is just a straight forward application of FFT to find the values of r_k for each k in (n +m) log( n + m) time.

Then for each r_k you must determine how big the overflow is and add it up accordingly. For squaring a number this means O(n log n) *arithmetic* operations.

You can add up the r_k values more efficiently using the Schönhage–Strassen algorithm to obtain a O(n log n log log n) bit operation bound.

The exact answer to your question is already posted by Eric Bainville.

However, you *can* get a much better bound than O(n^2) for squaring a number simply because there exist much better bounds for multiplying integers!

Comment: What does "in the arithmetic complexity only" mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you assume fixed length to the word size of the machine and that the number to be squared is in memory, a squaring operation requires only one load from memory, so could be faster.

For arbitrary length integers, multiplication is typically O(N²) but there are algorithms which reduce this for large integers.

If you assume the simple O(N²) approach to multiply *a* by *b*, then for each bit in *a* you have to shift *b* and add it to an accumulator if that bit is one. For each bit in *a* you need 3N shifts and additions.

Note that

```
( x - y )² = x² - 2 xy + y²
```

Hence

```
x² = ( x - y )² + 2 xy - y²
```

If each *y* is the largest power of two not greater than x, this gives a reduction to a lower square, two shifts and two additions. As *N* is reduced on each iteration, you may get an efficiency gain ( the symmetry means it visits each point in a triangle rather than a rectangle ), but it's still O(N²).

There may be another better symmetry to exploit.

Answer (score 0):

a^2
(a+b)*(a+b)+b^2  eg. 66^2 = (66+6)(66-6)+6^2 = 72*60+36= 4356

for a^n just use the power rule

66^4 = 4356^2

Answer (score 0):

I would want to solve the problem by N bit multiplication 
for a number

A the bits be A(n-1)A(n-2)........A(1)A(0).

B the bits be B(n-1)B(n-2)........B(1)B(0).

for the square of number A the unique multiplication bits generated will be 
for A(0)->A(0)....A(n-1)
    A(1)->A(1)....A(n-1) and so on
so the total operations will be

OP = n + n-1 + n-2 ....... + 1
Therefore OP = n^2+n/2;
so the Asymptotic notation will be O(n^2)

and for multiplication of A and B n^2 unique multiplications will be generated 
so the Asymptotic notation will be O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

`38` has a big-endian binary string representation `100110`. a ***MUCH*** cleaner way to think of that would be

---

```
2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(+1)+0)+0)+1)+1)+0 = 38
```

---

place all copies of the base on left side, and split the big-endian numeric string, one digit per layer, on right side.

This way it's easier to see the original `100110` in the new representation, while avoiding duplicative work, as each inner layer benefits from multiplications previously done

adapting a similar approach, certain merseene primes could also be expressed in this framework :

```
      2^(2^(2)-1)-1       => 2^(3)-1 | 7
   2^(2^(2^(2)-1)-1)-1    => 2^(7)-1 | 127
2^(2^(2^(2^(2)-1)-1)-1)-1 => 2^127-1 | 170141183460469231731687303715884105727
```

as well as generic powers of 2

(the `+0` are superfluous but included to make them comparable to above):

```
2^(2^(2^(2^(2)-1)+0)+1)+0 => 2^257 =>  231584178474632390847141970017375815706
                                       539969331281128078915168015826259279872
```

and **binary squaring** algorithm becomes just :

```
2*(2*(2*(2*(2)^2)^2)^2)^2-1 =      2147483647 = (3-1)^31-1
3*(3*(3*(3*(3)^2)^2)^2)^2-4 = 617673396283943 =   (3)^31-3-1
```

or say `6 ^ 61` - 61 has bin-string representation of :

```
   big-endian | 111101 
little-endian | 101111
```

and their corresponding **binary squaring** expression becomes

```
293242067884135544935936513642647623193965101056
293242067884135544935936513642647623193965101056
    # gawk profile, created Wed Aug 23 13:38:49 2023

    # BEGIN rule(s)

    BEGIN {
  1     print (((((6) ^ 2 * 6) ^ 2 * 6) ^ 2 * 6) ^ 2 * 1) ^ 2 * 6
  1     print 6 * (1 * (6 * (6 * (6 * (6) ^ 2) ^ 2) ^ 2) ^ 2) ^ 2
    }
```

And you can see how few arithmetic ops are needed to get to that large value.

Answer (score -1):

The square root of 2<sup>n</sup> is 2<sup>n / 2</sup> or 2<sup>n >> 1</sup>, so if your number is a power of two everything is totally simple once you know the power. To multiply is even simplier: 2<sup>4</sup> * 2<sup>8</sup> is 2<sup>4+8</sup>. There's no sense in this statements you've done.

Comment: How does this relate in any way to the question?

Comment: It doesn't.  The "binary number" in the question just means "integer".

Comment: The question itself is nonsense, I was trying to find a explanation which justify the heresies he said.

Comment: See Mike Thompsons answer, he explains it perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a binary number A, it can (always, proof left to the eager reader) be expressed as (2^n + B), this can be squared as 2^2n + 2^(n+1)B + B^2. We can then repeat the expansion, until such a point that B equals zero. I haven't looked too hard at it, but intuitively, it feels as if you should be able to make a squaring function take fewer algorithmical steps than a general-purpose multiplication.

Answer (score -4):

I think that you are completely wrong in your statements

> Multiplying two binary numbers takes
>   n^2 time

Multiplying two 32bit numbers take exactly one clock cycle. On a 64 bit processor, I would assume that multiplying two 64 bit numbers take exactly 1 clock cycle. It wouldn't even surprise my that a 32bit processor can multiply two 64bit numbers in 1 clock cycle.

```
yet squaring a number can be done more efficiently somehow.
```

Squaring a number is just multiplying the number with itself, so that is just a simple multiplication. There is no "square" operation in the CPU.

Maybe you are confusing "squaring" with "multiplying by a power of 2". Multiplying by 2 can be implemeted by shifting all the bits one position to the "left". Multiplying by 4 is shifting all the bits two positions to the "left". By 8, 3 positions. But this trick only applies to a power of two.

Comment: Think bigger -- as in multiplying numbers with thousands of bits.

Comment: 32bit `mul` operation depends on the chip and on the numbers. Usually it takes ~8-20 cycles. I believe ARM processors have very fast `mul` operation.

Comment: 32 bit multiplies haven't taken 20 cycles in a long, long time, except on the most limited hardware.

Comment: Aah - I see I am mistaken on normal CPUs multiplying in 1 clock cycle. DSP processors does it though.